# How to test data within a string without using another string

Tags: java, string

Is it possible to test the data within a string without using another string? For example, if I wanted to test whether String size=("large") is it possible without having to create a second string with the value as large and comparing it using .equals? Is it possible to test case as well (i.e. not using .equalsignorecase)?

Comment: How would you describe the substring without using a string in a sane fashion?

Comment: No, you will always have to present a string as condition: `if(myString.equals("large")`. You could add some interning beforehand and stuff, but ask yourself if that is really important.

Comment: I suppose you could avoid creating a `String` by creating a `char[]` and writing your own matching code. But why on earth would you want to do this?

Comment: I only want to compare 3 things and thought it would be quicker to just do that. Aw well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a conditional statement you need to compare using the .equals(....) method or .equalsIgnoreCase(...).  As far as testing for upper and lower case of characters, take a look at the [Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class in the javadocs.  I believe you'll find methods like: isLetter() and isUpperCase() and isLowerCase().  Just use a loop to iterate over the string and evaluate over every character.